# Google Play Developer Console - How to Remove App from "Family Library" Eligibility?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I'm setting up an app on Google Play and I notice this text on its Play Store page:

**Eligible for Family Library**

Eligible if bought after 7/2/2016. *Learn More*

Our app is going to be subscription based per install. We don't want it shared between devices under a single subscription. How can I remove/opt-out-of Family Library eligibility?

I've been trying to search Google for answers, but everything I'm finding is about how to manage apps in a Family Library as a user; not as a developer. Heck, Stack Overflow doesn't even have any **tags** relating to Google Play's "Family-Library"! Or am I missing something important here?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible!
If you are selling your app via Google Play, it will always be accessible by all family members.

I think you can avoid this by using in-app purchases and (maybe) subscription instead.